# Insert chosen number within range, squared and cubed

Tags: ruby, integer

I am trying to set a range for allowed user inputted numbers. Then, I want to print that chosen number squared and cubed.

I tried the following:

```
class Range
  def clamp(min, max)
    self < min ? min : self > max ? max : self
  end
end

class Multiply
  def initialize(id, squared, cubed)
    @id     = num
    @squared   = (num * num)
    @cubed = (num * num * num)
  end
end

# @limit = (params[:limit] || 10).clamp(0, 100)

puts 'Please insert your favorite number between 1 and 100.'
num = gets.to_i
puts 'You picked ' + num.to_s + '?'
puts 'You picked ' + num.to_s.Multiply.squared + '?'
```

The `@limit` throws `'params' not found`.

How can I run `num` through classes `Range` and `Multiply` before it `puts`?

Comment: Please ask one question per question. Why would `params` be found when you did not define it? Also, please state what you actually want to happen, as "run my num variable through both my classes" is not at all clear. What do you want to get? A square of a clamped number? A clamp of a cubed number?

Comment: Are you aware that [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Range.html) is one of Ruby's built-in core classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to set a range for 'allowed' user inputted numbers, then I
>   want to print that chosen number squared, and cubed.

Use the [`clamp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp) method available to [`Numeric`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Numeric.html) via the [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html) module:

```
input = '110'
clamped = input.to_i.clamp(0,100)

puts clamped
#100
```

You can attain powers of numbers with [`Integer#**`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Integer.html#method-i-2A-2A) or [`Float#**`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Float.html#method-i-2A-2A). If one must produce DIY methods by extending core classes, then you can for example extend the `Numeric` class by defining the methods `clamp`, `square` and `cube` there. `square` could be:

```
class Numeric
  def square
    self ** 2
  end
end

10.square #=> 100
```